# Cannot understand shift operator behavior in C code

Tags: c, bit-shift

Look at this sample C code (extracted a test case as an example):

```
main() {
  unsigned long a, b;
  int c;
  c = 32;
  a = 0xffffffff << 32;
  b = 0xffffffff << c;
  printf ("a=%x, b=%x\n", a, b);
}
```

Prints: `a=0, b=ffffffff`

I cannot understand why b is not zero, just like a. I tested this on Microsoft C and GCC.

**Update**: I fixed the stupid typo (should have been << c and not << b of course). But my question still stands, e.g. the result is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C it is undefined behavior to left shift more than the width of the promoted operand.

> (C99, 6.5.7p3) "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

I assume in the examples below `int` and `unsigned int` types are 32-bit.

The type of an unsuffixed hexadecimal integer constant is the first in the corresponding list in which its value can be represented: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`.

So here `0xFFFFFFFF`  is of type `unsigned int` and `0xFFFFFFFF << 32` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You offer a good amount of detail for part a of the question, but nothing to explain part b.

Comment: @BitBank because part `a` and part `b` is the same problem (same left shift is performed) with the same explanation.  Both expressions in the RHS of the assignment of `a` and `b` are undefined behavior. As it is undefined behavior, the result of `a` and `b` can be the same or can be different or the program can `rm -rf` the root partition. Of course, we can observe different compilation heuristics because in this first case a constant is used as the right operand of the shift, but this is irrelevant.

Comment: All those details that you've presented may help some people to abandon using ints, longs etc in favor of using typedefs/definitions  like INT32, UINT32, INT8, UINT8, INT64, UINT64 in projects. They make code clearer and less error prone and one no longer has to be worried about ints changing size depending on compiler/cpu/compiler options etc. You (depending on your underlying env just once define (U)INT(8/16/32/64) etc..

Comment: Part a and part b are completely different. Part a is a compiler behavior and part b is a CPU behavior. It is completely relevant that it is out of the compiler's control when a shift is done by a variable amount. It is encoded as machine instructions and runs as it will run...

Comment: @BitBank as I explained in my last comment this is irrelevant. Both expressions are undefined behavior for the exact same reason.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the operation he tried to perform is an undefined behavior. He asked why he got the results that he did. Your explanation is fine for part a, but provides nothing to explain part b.

Comment: @BitBank You are wrong, and ouah is right. The behavior is undefined in both cases, and for the very same reason. The C standard knows nothing about CPUs, and anyway it's pointless to try to reason about the output (and why they are different), because UB us UB.

Comment: The type of an unsuffixed hexadecimal integer constant is the first in the corresponding list in which its value can be represented: int, UNSIGNED INT, long, unsigned long

Comment: @xiaokaoy any disagreement with that?

Comment: I mean, you were wrong about the type of an unsuffixed hexadecimal integer constant in C89. Actually this is the same as C99 specifies, except that the type can be (unsigned) long long in C99.

Comment: @xiaokaoy woo good catch. I cannot believe this went unnoticed for so long. Thanks, I edited the answer and removed the C89 part.

Answer (score 6):

You never initialized `b` to anything before you use it here:

```
b = 0xffffffff << b;
```

So it can be anything. (I think you actually meant to shift by `c`.)

---

That aside:

The main issue is that shifting by the # of bits in the datatype or more is **undefined behavior**.
So if the literal `0xffffffff` is a 32-bit integer, then the line:

```
a = 0xffffffff << 32;
```

is not defined by the standard. (See comments.)

---

You should also be getting a compiler warning:

```
warning C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

Comment: why the *so if unsigned long is only 32-bits*? if `unsigned int` is 32-bit then `0xffffffff << 32` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I bet that after fixing your typo you get 2 zeros as a result. Here is why:
If your program is (I bet is) compiled as release you have optimisations turned on. This means that compiler will use so called "constant folding" and CPU will not even perform these shifts. Under the hood code will have 2 zero constants pushed onto the stack and invoke printf. Results of these operations (shifts) will essentially become constants in the program. So there are no undefined behaviours etc. - your a and b becomes constant values and you'll get sth like:

```
push 0
push 0
push offset to printf format string
call to printf
```

Comment: Well obviously this code is just a sample I banged together to analyze a problem in a production code, but you're right: with `gcc -O3` I get two zeros, and with `gcc -O0` I get 0 and 0xffffffff.

Comment: So in debug mode (no optimizations) you get in first case 0 (compiler makes it constant hence 0). Second case shows you are using x86 cpu where number of bits to shift left is masked (with 31) so essentially you always shift left by (operand << (count & 0x1F)) and hence (0xFFFFFFFF << 0) leads to unchanged 'b'. (Can verify that in "Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference" (very useful stuff)

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has mentioned another interesting aspect of the problem. On x86 computers, the shift amount is used modulus 32, so a shift by 32 will really be a shift by 0. On ARM machines, the shift value (if coming from a register) is not altered, so any shift value of 32 or greater will always result in 0 in the destination register.

Specifically in your problem, the compiler is smart about the constant values, so it turns (0xffffffff << 32) into the correct value (0). In your second example, the compiler can't directly calculate the shift amount since it's coming from a variable. When executed on an Intel machine, shifting left by 32 results in a shift left by 0.

Comment: This is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You have `b = 0xffffffff << b;`, but perhaps you meant `b = 0xffffffff << c;`

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be zero? You shift it by a garbage number (the first value of `b`) that can be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize B, so it's going to have whatever (random) value is at at that particular memory location at the time the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you get to the line `b = 0xffffffff << b;`, the value of b has not been assigned. It looks like its value is zero, making the instruction `b = 0xffffffff << b;`. Which expalins the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is AND after shift. In this case you know stritcly whats happen.

Examply:

```
b << = 4;
b &= 0xfffffff0;
```